# Create and Edit reg key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, registry

I am trying to create and edit a reg key in ruby but keep getting the following error:

```
setKeyStringValue error:
false
error in 'open' system cannot find file specified
```

My code:

```
require 'win32/registry' 

$hkey_local_machine=Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
$hkey_current_user=Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER  

# Returns the Microsoft Registry path to the Microsoft software information 
def getKeyValue(hive, key_path, key_name) 
  reg_obj=hive.open(key_path, Win32::Registry::KEY_READ) 
  begin 
          reg_typ, reg_val = reg_obj.read(key_name) 
   rescue Win32::Registry::Error 
          puts "key not found : #{key_name}" 
    end 
    return reg_val 
end 

#used to set a String value for a key 
def setKeyStringValue(hive,key_path, key_name, key_value) 
begin
    reg_key=hive.open(key_path, Win32::Registry::KEY_WRITE) 
    puts "opened key"
    reg_key.write(key_name,Win32::Registry::REG_SZ,key_value) 
rescue Win32::Registry::Error 
    puts "setKeyStringValue error:"
    return false
end 
return true
end 

puts setKeyStringValue(Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\PsychSoft","foo","woo")

puts getKeyValue(Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\PsychSoft","foo")
```

Can someone explain why this code doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your registry path needs to be enclosed in single '
Your code works like this

```
profiles_key = 'Software\Microsoft'

puts setKeyStringValue(Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER, profiles_key, "foo", "woo")

puts getKeyValue(Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER, profiles_key, "foo")
```

Which gives

```
opened key
true
woo
```

Comment: Yep, I had two problems, the hive (Software\Psychsoft) had to be replaced with one that actually existed (Software\Microsoft) then I needed to remove the extra slash which meant I needed to change the quotes to single.